# Ansible deployments in the production envirnment of web developement

Tags: azure-devops

**earlier so many times Ansible deployments used to Happen in Production environment With help of Ansible server and Host patterns where we were used to create groups in the inventory file and used to deploy on that group but now days k8s cluster or docker swarm kind of approach is used mostly?why this shift happened....is ansible deployments are no more relevant even for small enterprises

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.